# How do I fetch a single model in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, rest, backbone.js

I have a `Clock` model in Backbone:

```
var Clock = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

I'm trying to get an instance of that that has the latest information from `/clocks/123`. Some things I've tried:

#### a "class"-level method

```
Clock.fetch(123)
// TypeError: Object function (){ ... } has no method 'fetch'
```

#### creating an instance and then calling `fetch` on it:

```
c = new Clock({id: 123})
c.fetch()
// Error: A 'url' property or function must be specified
```

#### a collection

I tried creating an `AllClocks` collection resource (even though I have no use for such a thing on the page):

```
var AllClocks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Clock,
  url: '/clocks/'
});
var allClocks = new AllClocks();
allClocks.fetch(123);
// returns everything from /clocks/
```

How do I just get **one** API-backed Clock?

Comment: IMHO it belongs to the collection. Something like Collection#fetchOne(id, callback).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your second approach is the approach I have used. Try adding the following to your Clock model:

```
url : function() {
  var base = 'clocks';
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
},
```

This approach assumes that you have implemented controllers with the hashbang in your URL like so, http://www.mydomain.com/#clocks/123 , but it should work even if you haven't yet.

Comment: There is a way to avoid this as explained in Backbone Model documentation http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url

Comment: @makevoid your I could not make work the example you provide in coffee script or the one in the documentation, the Andrew example works, could you provide and example with foo.url(), it always tell me that there's no function url.

Comment: @makevoid it seems the method you are referring to only works if the model has been created in a collection. Notice the collection in `[collection.url]/[id]`.

Comment: @makevoid can you please provide a working link? unfortunately, this one is broken for now

Comment: here's the working link (they moved the doc! wow, 5 years passed, geez): 
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url  - @StevenDevijver is correct

Answer (score 137):

Try specifying [urlRoot](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot) in the model:

From the docs:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/books'});
var solaris = new Book({id: "1083-lem-solaris"});
solaris.fetch();
```

Comment: This is good, but sometimes you don't want to reinstantiate the model. If you want to fetch a specific item against the same model, you can do a silent set: `currentBook.set('id', 13423, {silent:true})`. This works too, but I'm not sure why: `currentBook.id = 13423`

Comment: @SimplGy that works because `model.id` is essentially synonymous with `model.attributes.id`. If you call `model.set('id')`, Backbone sets `model.id` to whatever you specified. And `model.id` is what gets used when creating the model-specific URL.

Answer (score 26):

I personally recommend, following the [Model#url method documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url)

```
model = new Model(id: 1)
view = new View(model: model) 
collection = new Collection([model])
model.fetch()
```

in your collection remember to add the collection url:

```
url: "/models"
```

and in your View's initialize function do:

```
this.model.bind("change", this.render)
```

this way backbone will do an ajax request using this url:

```
"/models/1"
```

your model will be updated and the view rendered, without modifying Collection#url or Model#urlRoot

note:
sorry this example came out in coffee script, but you can easily translate it to js adding var statements

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work. Don't even makes a call to the server when calling fetch in the model (nor the collection)

Comment: This looks fine, but the collection line looks awkward in cases when we don't really need the collection.

Comment: i couldn't get this to work: this.model.get('field'). Looks like the model is is created sub object

Comment: this.model.bind("change", this.render, this) worked well for me

Comment: is this coffeescript?

Comment: @UlysseBN yes (was year 2011), you can add var statements, `{}` inside the `()`'s for the passed objects and optional `;` ad the end of the lines

Answer (score 12):

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/person/details'});
var myName = new Person({id: "12345"});
myName.fetch();
```

As a result you make a Ajax request on the

```
URL http://[domainName]/person/details/id
```

and you have the JSON response back.

Enjoiiii !!!

Comment: this is the same solution as @Hernan

Answer (score 0):

...and do this if you don't want the trailing slash on the model urlRoot:

```
    url : function() {                        
        return this.urlRoot + this.id;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be accessing the object trough a collection and keeping it in the collection all the time. This is how to do it:

```
var AllClocks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Clock,
  url: '/clocks/'
});

var allClocks = new AllClocks();
my_clock = allClocks.add({id: 123});
my_clock.fetch()
```

Comment: You don't know that.  Maybe all he requires is one Clock.  Suppose I want to present a client with a single Model of a User record?  Should he have access to a Collection of all Users too?

Sometimes folk just need some advice while trying to keep their usecase private.  Just answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use RESTful url,but I couldn't understand why 'postId' can't be added to base url.

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'getBlogPost',
    defaults: {
        postTitle: "defaultTitle",
        postTime: "1970-01-01",
        postContent: "defaultContent",
        postAuthor: "anonymous"
    }
});

var post = new PostModel({
            postId: 1
        });
alert(post.url());
```

Then I know only after I set 'idAttribute' as 'postId' in Model can I get the right url.
like this:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'postId',
    urlRoot: 'getBlogPost',
    defaults: {
        postTitle: "defaultTitle",
        postTime: "1970-01-01",
        postContent: "defaultContent",
        postAuthor: "anonymous"
    }
});
```