# Backbone model is not getting populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
app.Model.BrandModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'brandId',
  defaults: {
    name : '',
    description : '',
    brandImage : '',
    user : '',
    showPro : false,
    proDescription : ''
  },
  url : function(){
    return '/rest/brands/' + brandId;
  }
 });
```

I can see from firebug that my my server is returning the following JSON response.Also the request is successful.

```
brandId "fc692c70-4096-11e3-a0f2-3c970e02b4ec"
name "Galeria"
user "940ee800-4090-11e3-80c0-3c970e02b4ec"
description "This is galeria"
brandImage "/brand-images/fc692c70-...3-a0f2-3c970e02b4ec.jpg"
proDescription ""
showPro false
```

I am  calling like this.

```
var brandModel = new app.Model.BrandModel();
brandModel.fetch();
```

but my model is not getting populated and the values are still default one.

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/brands/{brandId}",
       method = RequestMethod.GET,
       produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable("brandId") String brandId, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request, so I passeed [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) a success callback and now i am seeing the modal values.

```
brandModel.fetch({
   success: function(){
       console.log(brandModel.toJSON());  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are telling your code WHICH brandId to fetch...  Have you tried this?

```
var brandModel = new app.Model.BrandModel({brandId: "fc692c70-4096-11e3-a0f2-3c970e02b4ec"});
brandModel.fetch();
```

More information: [How do I fetch a single model in Backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097107/how-do-i-fetch-a-single-model-in-backbone)

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
app.Model.BrandModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'brandId',
  urlRoot : '/rest/brands/',
  defaults: {
    name : '',
    description : '',
    brandImage : '',
    user : '',
    showPro : false,
    proDescription : ''
  }
 });
```

Then like @David mentioned:

```
var brandModel = new app.Model.BrandModel({brandId: "fc692c70-4096-11e3-a0f2-3c970e02b4ec"});
brandModel.fetch();
```

Answer (score -1):

Also `return '/rest/brands/' + brandId;` probably should be `return '/rest/brands/' + this.get("brandId");`