# Why is this Backbone model's attribute undefined when I try to get it?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I've got a simple REST API that gives me data about an item at `/api/items/:id`, including ID and name. I'm using a Router to organise my Backbone views. The `edit` route instantiates a FormEditItem view, passing it the ID from the URL.

To get the data for the model from the API, the form view instantiates a new model, sets the ID and then calls the model's fetch method. (The second approach recommended in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097107/how-do-i-fetch-a-single-model-in-backbone).)

The model declaration is extremely simple:

```
App.Models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: 'api/items'

});
```

And this is my form view:

```
App.Views.FormEditItem = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#tpl-formEditItem').html()),

    initialize: function(opts) {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.modelID = opts.modelID;
        this.parent = opts.parent;
        this.model = new App.Models.Item({id: this.modelID});
        this.model.fetch();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('Starting render:', this.model);
        console.log(this.model.get('name'));
        this.parent.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});
```

In my form view's render function I'm logging out the model. I can see the model's attributes. But on the next line, when I try to log out the results of get('name'), I get undefined!

[image]

What's going on? Do I need to define a model's attributes before I try to fetch them from the database?

=============================================================================

EDIT

Following Stephen and Rida's advice, the fix in this situation is to add an event listener to the model's `change` event. The `fetch` operation takes some time to get the data from the API: I was trying to output the data before it arrived. So my initialize function should read:

```
    initialize: function(opts) {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.modelID = opts.modelID;
        this.parent = opts.parent;
        this.model = new App.Models.Item({id: this.modelID});
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
    }
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: No you don't. The source code for `get` is simple: `return this.attributes[attr];` Just checking, but are you sure you've copied the code correctly in the question?

Comment: Will elaborate in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to render the view before the fetch completes. In initialize, you call

```
this.model.fetch()
```

and then immediately call

```
this.render()
```

At that point the fetch won't have completed, so there won't be a `name` attribute.

When you look at the model in the console, that's after the fetch has completed, so then there is a `name`

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, you're absolutely right. Rida posted a very similar answer, but yours came in first. When I change my code as above the view renders the data and the attribute logs out fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of these lines :

```
this.model.fetch();
this.render();
```

try to do

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

Comment: Thanks Rida, Stephen's answer came in first, but I've given yours an upvote.